# MySQL Stored Procedure Updating Multiple Databases

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble understanding how this stored procedure functions. I understand that its supposed to update the bookings table however I do not understand the complete syntax and what this procedure is doing under the hood

```
CREATE PROCEDURE make_booking (IN p_room_id VARCHAR(255), IN p_booked_date DATE, IN p_booked_time 
TIME, IN p_member_id VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE v_price DECIMAL(6, 2);
DECLARE v_payment_due DECIMAL(6, 2);    
SELECT price INTO v_price FROM rooms WHERE id = p_room_id;  
INSERT INTO bookings (room_id, booked_date, booked_time, member_id) VALUES (p_room_id, 
p_booked_date, p_booked_time, p_member_id); 
SELECT payment_due INTO v_payment_due FROM members WHERE id = p_member_id;
UPDATE members SET payment_due = v_payment_due + v_price WHERE id = p_member_id;    
END $$;
```

The tables involved and their relevant fields are provided below for reference:

rooms:      id, room_type, price
bookings:   id, room_id, booked_date, booked_time, member_id, datetime_of_booking, payment_status
members:    id, password, email, member_since, payment_due

Thank You Again!

Comment: Your code does not update multiple databases. It inserts a record into a **table**, then updates another **table**. What exactly is unclear in the code? Pls be specific! Furthermore, the stored proc is not doing anything more under the hood because it does not call any custom stored proc or function. These are plain and simple sql statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotated with comments to hopefully explain what's going on here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE make_booking (IN p_room_id VARCHAR(255), IN p_booked_date DATE, IN p_booked_time 
TIME, IN p_member_id VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

/* Declare some temporary variables to hold some data that we'll be SELECTing later */
DECLARE v_price DECIMAL(6, 2);
DECLARE v_payment_due DECIMAL(6, 2);    

/* SELECT the price of the room and put it into the v_price variable */
SELECT price INTO v_price FROM rooms WHERE id = p_room_id;  

/* INSERT a record into the bookings table for the room and member */
INSERT INTO bookings (room_id, booked_date, booked_time, member_id) VALUES (p_room_id, 
p_booked_date, p_booked_time, p_member_id); 

/* Get the current payment due for the member and put it into the v_payment_due variable */
SELECT payment_due INTO v_payment_due FROM members WHERE id = p_member_id;

/* Update the payment due for the member to whatever it was before plus the price of the room we put into v_price earlier */
UPDATE members SET payment_due = v_payment_due + v_price WHERE id = p_member_id;  

END $$;
```